# Calculating a rate with a single summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have a $n$ events, each with some value $x$ and duration $t$. I can calculate the global rate as follows:
$$\text{rate} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nt_i}$$

Is it possible (or provably impossible) to calculate a global rate with a single summation over the events:
$$\text{rate} = \sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i, t_i)\text{ ?}$$

Comment: if $f(x,t)$ does not depend on $n$ then you have $f(x, t)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^1f(x, t)=\sum_{i=1}^2f(x, t)=2f(x, t)$ for any $x,t \gt 0$ meaning $f(x, t)=0$ and so not a rate.

Comment: But why? Because computational speaking a single sum and the quotient of sums are of the same big oh scale I.e O(n).

Comment: @Chinny84 I am using some visualisation software that can sum across database entries, but nothing more complex. I solved my visualisation problem another way, but was curious if this could be proved mathematically impossible.

Comment: Cheers for that. Out of interest myself, which visualisation and DB are you using?

Comment: [Kibana3](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) and [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). I think the latest Kibana4 can handle more complicated logic.

Comment: Yes I have heard of both. And used the later.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}$$

On the second definition take the derivative respect to $x_i$:

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial f(x_i,t_i)}{\partial x_i}$$

Equating both for $i=1$:

$$\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}=\frac{\partial f(x_1,t_1)}{\partial x_i}$$

Integrating respect to $x_1$:

$$\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}+g(x_2,\cdots,x_n)=f(x_1,t_1)$$

Obviously (the derivatives are zero):

$$g(x_2,\cdots,x_n)=c$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}+c=f(x_1,t_1)$$

Clearly this give a contradiction (because the value of $t_1$ is conditionated by the other $t_i$)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it is impossible.

Let:$${\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i} \over \sum_{i=1}^n{t_i}}=\sum_{i=1}^n{f(x_i,t_i)}$$
We can write it as:$${X_n \over T_n}=F_n$$
Or:$${X_n}=F_n T_n$$
$${\partial {X_n} \over \partial {x_i}}={\partial {F_n} \over \partial {x_i}}T_n+F_n{\partial {T_n} \over \partial {x_i}}$$
$$1={\partial {f_i} \over \partial {x_i}}T_n+0$$
$$\left ({\partial {f_i} \over \partial {x_i}} \right )^{-1}={T_n}$$
Let:
$$u(x_i,t_i)=\left ({\partial {f_i} \over \partial {x_i}} \right )^{-1}$$
$${\partial \over \partial {t_j}}u(x_i,t_i)={\partial {T_n} \over \partial {t_j}}$$
This yields:
$$0=1$$